# how to change background color of flatlist for array ans elements?

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I want to change the background color of flatlist item according to array ans but not able to change
background-color of flatlist only 1st item background color is changed

```
    const ans = [1, 3, 5];
    const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
    let items = Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map((v, i) => {
        return {
            id: i + 1,
        };
    });
    setDataSource(items);
    }, []);
   
    const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        const backgroundColor = item.id == ans[index] ? '#00b300' : "#F5FCFF"; \\ here is main code
       
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
                <View style={{ ...styles.viewStyle, backgroundColor: backgroundColor, flex: 1 / 5, 
                             height: 40, }} >
                    <Text style={{ ...styles.cardView_Text, color: '#000' }} > {item.id} </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    };

    const getItem = (item) => {
        // alert('Id: ' + item.id);
    };

   <FlatList
    data={dataSource}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    extraData={selectedId}
    numColumns={5}
    initialNumToRender={2}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
    windowSize={7}
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`===` is a strict equality comparison operator in JavaScript, which returns false for the values which are not of a similar type. This operator performs type casting for equality. If we compare 2 with "2" using ===, then it will return a false value.

try changing it to `==` will solve your problem.
One more thing please recheck the useState() and useEffect(). Change it to useEffect(),
I have added a demo link, Please have a look [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-franklin-vg139?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: const dataSource = [
    {
      id: 1
    },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4 },
    { id: 5 }
  ]; i want to change color for const ans = [1,3,5]; @Rajshekhar Yadav

Comment: I have added a few changes [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-franklin-vg139?file=/src/App.js) In this scenario the 1st 3rd and 5th Index should be highlighted, Correct?. You have to use `includes` function. I hope that will help.

Comment: it worked fine. what if I have three array const ans = [1,3,5];  const notans = [2,4,6]; and const visit=[7,8,9] ; and i want to change const dataSource = [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6}, { id: 7 }, { id: 8 }, { id: 9},  ]  background color green for ans , red for notans and white for visit?

Comment: U just have to make some conditions. I added the link [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-franklin-vg139?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

what is `quesno` in your case?
and I think you are using useState instead of useEffect.

```
useState(() => {..}) => useEffect(() => {..})
```

if you still want to use === and let the code work fine change the function to

```
const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        const backgroundColor = item.id === ans[index];
       
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
                <View style={{ ...styles.viewStyle, backgroundColor: backgroundColor  ? '#00b300' : "#F5FCFF" , flex: 1 / 5, 
                             height: 40, }} >
                    <Text style={{ ...styles.cardView_Text, color: '#000' }} > {item.id} </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    };
```

Comment: it can be any number

Comment: @Rajshekhar Yadav answered my query